# codeigniter pagination links showing wrong url

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, pagination

I have faced a problem in Codeigniter pagination while my links are not working properly 
here is my code in the controller:

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');


    $data['base_url'] = base_url().'search/?loc='.$loc.'&cats='.$cats;


    $data['total_rows'] = $total_data; // here print the total rows like 50, 100 etc
    $data['per_page'] = 25; 

    $data['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $data['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($data);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

when print links in view page using

```
<?php echo $links;?>
```

in the pagination links, it showing the wrong URL like

> https://localhost/home/search?loc=BD&cats=123/2  //wrong url

but I want to like this:

> https://localhost/home/search?loc=BD&cats=123&page=2  //need like this url

This will work for me. Can anyone please fix my bug?

Comment: did you check  $data['base_url'] = base_url().'/'.$loc.'/'.$cats; print_r($data['base_url]);exit; what you get there ?

Comment: i updated my question, please check @BoominathanElango

Answer (score 0):

> Change

```
 $data['base_url'] = base_url().'search/?loc='.$loc.'&cats='.$cats;
```

> Into

```
 $data['base_url'] = base_url().'search?loc='.$loc.'&cats='.$cats;
```

> Hope this Helps!!

Comment: not working still facing wrong url `&page=/2` I wanna `&page=2` like this one

Comment: you can get the page no using $page_no = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: In routes.php $routes['search/(:num)'] = 'search'; Made like this

Comment: please read again my question i think you don't understand what am I saying?